# How do I add data to other tables when creating a post?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, forms, eloquent

There is a table post, to it with the help of hasMany attached 4 more tables, in which almost the same fields, namely the tables(store, address, number, buy).All data must be filled in when writing the post
**PostContorller@store**

```php
function storee(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request,[
'name' => 'required'
]);
$post = Post = Post::query()->create([
'name' => $request->get('name'),
'decr' => $request->get('decr'),
]);
}
```

**Model Post**

```php
public function getStoreForPost() 
{
 return $this->hasMany(Store::class);
}
```

**view creat post**

```php
@extends('index')
 
@section('content')
<form method="post" action="{{ route('post.store') }}">
    @csrf
    <div align="center">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 25px;">
            <label for="name">Post name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        </div>
        <div style="padding-bottom: 25px;">
            <label for="description">Post Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="decr" id="description">
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <div class="store" align="center" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <button class="store_add" type="button">Add Store</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div>
            <label for="getStoreForPost">Store</label>
                <input type="text" id="store_name" name="store_name[]">
                <input type="text" id="store_link" name="store_link[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
    <button type="submit">Add Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
@endsection
 
@push('script')
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".store_add").on('click',function(){
            $(".store").append(
              `<div style="padding: 10px 0">
                <label for="getStoreForPost">Store</label>
                    <input type="text" id="store_name" name="store_name[]">
                    <input type="text" id="store_link" name="store_link[]">
              </div>`
            );
        });
        
    });
@endpush
```

When I try to add a post, I get error 1364, can't fill in a field that doesn't have null properties. This is understandable that I did not specify what to fill in.So I decided to add new tricks to the controller.

```php
$post->getStoreForHouse()->create([
'name' => $request->get('store_name'),
'url' => $request->get('store_url')
]);
```

**Migrations**
**post_migration**

```php
$table->string('name');
$table->text('decr')->nullable();
```

**store_migration**

```php
$table->string('store_name');
$table->text('store_link');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id')->nullable();
$table->foregin('post_id)->references('id')->on('posts');
```

**Model Store**

```php
use App\Models\Post;

use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'store';

protected $fillable = ['store_name', 'store_url'];
protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function post()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

But nothing has changed, no matter how I try to crawl out oishbka 1364 or an error in the request ::create-there is no instruction for this action
UPD:
If I fill in the fields via pma, then all the data is output and works as it should, that is, I manually fill in the post table for the test (post name, post description), then go to the store table , and there I add the store name and the store url, as well as attach it to a specific entry in the post table. It turns out that when I go to the page with viewing this post, I see all the lines that I attached to it in pma.

*Please help me, I've already filled my head with this.*

Comment: If you have 4 tables with the same headers, you should probably just combine them to a single table with a column indicating a type of record.

Comment: Can you show the exact error message? it usually tells you exactly what you are missing from filling?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, They are almost the same fields I have, not all of them. And there I need the tables just to collect the data. But at the moment I am only interested in how to add data to other tables in the same form when creating a post.

Comment: @mrhn,
`BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::create does not exist.`

Comment: Your code should not throw that exception please update the code included

Answer (score 0):

Okay so each one of these relations need to be looked at separately, since as you mentioned in your replies - they have to be different tables.

```
$post = Post::query()->create([
'name' => $request->get('name'),
'decr' => $request->get('decr'),
]);
```

that should work just fine, if you need other values to be nullable or default to a value, you need to set that via a migration on the database.

Further,

```
BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::create does not exist.
```

means that you have picked a collection (probably via a relation) and then called the function, so something like:

```
$post->addresses->create(['whatever'=>'data']);
```

If you edit your message and add information with the code of your Models, as well as potentially migrations (or at least the picture of it in phpMyAdmin or something else), then we will be able to help you, but until that, its a crystal ball foretelling.